# Facebook loading multiple picture url for custom friend selector

Tags: facebook, image, mobile, load

I'm building a custom friend selector on mobile (Air, starling). I use the graph api to request invitable_friends which returns me everything i need.

My concern is about loading all these images. The basic strategy would be to loop over all the output and load all image separately.
First, i'm afraid that will be very slow and heavy for the user, 
Second, i'm afraid facebook will blacklist the incoming connection if it gets too many calls.

So my question is, is there any specific strategy, as caching the images on the mobile harddrive to load them only once (and refresh once in a while)
Or does facebook another way to access all those data in a single request ?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no way to request all profile images in a single request, you need to make one HTTP request for each one. Is your “concern” based on any actual negative experience with doing so?

Comment: yes, i tried in a real situation (loading all my friends https url links), it takes a very long time, somtime the query seems to be blocked and some images don't come. I guess, at least i must absolutely use a cache system to fasten the speed for future display

Comment: Well, try some “lazy loading” implementation/plugin perhaps. Not all pictures will be shown on one screen anyway I assume, there will likely be some scrolling involved for a larger number of friends(?).

Comment: Thanks but i think i will forget the thumbs in my friend selector. It will probably slow down too much performance, and it's a pain in the ass to develop. Thanks for your suggestions though